# Past Continuous with Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-continuous, sequence-of-tenses

Although I know the rules of PC and PP usage, I want to ask if that combination of tenses is okay. Can I use PC and PP together here?

> You remember, I *was writing* an essay [1] on my computer and I *have finished* it [2].

[1] simply tells the person that I was doing something and it is just a fact while [2] emphasizes the fact that it has been finished (we don't know when, it could be finished a while ago etc). I believe I can say such sentence to somebody who saw me writing an essay and later I am telling them it is done.

Or maybe I should say it this way:

> You remember, I was writing an essay on my computer and I finished it.

What about this:

> I have finished the essay I have been writing.
>
> I have finished the essay I was writing.

Are the sentences okay?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every one of them has a slightly different meaning. They are all right.

Comment: The first one is marginal.  Am I remembering that you finished it? Is that your intended meaning? Or have you finished the essay that I remember you were writing?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

I have finished the essay **I had been** writing.

Comment: -1 because it's awkward. Much more fluent to say "I have finished the essay I was writing."

Comment: Correct! But I tried to use the structure the writer asked. Otherwise there are zillion ways to state the meaning.

Comment: Sometimes the right answer is a different answer. Don't let OP paint you into a corner!

Comment: I don't see it as awkward. It might even be more suitable, depending on the context.

Comment: @Robusto Alright! I'll do mate.

Comment: Or *I finished the essay I've been writing*.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing whatever wrong with it, except that I feel an urge to add a word like "now" or "but"  before "I have finished it". If you use "but" it replaces "and". "And" by itself suggests a continuity which makes the change of tense slightly jarring.

The other sentences are perfectly alright. Indeed you could say "I am finishing the essay I have been writing", or even "I will finish the essay I have been writing,  tomorrow."